# Passing arraylist data to custom adapter with retrofit

Tags: android, arraylist, retrofit

I have a service that returns some data, I can already get this data with toast, but I wanted to include it in an ArrayList to be read by my custom adapter, there is an example i using dummy static data, but i just have no idea how to store it after i got data from retrofit.

HomeFragment

```
// dummy data
public static ArrayList<Content> initContents() {
    ArrayList<Content> listContent = new ArrayList<>();
    listContent.add(new Content("Cinque Terre", "The coastline, the five villages in Italy.", "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-lYvUYANw3HQ/XY6etG5U8ZI/AAAAAAAAOlc/7uOsI_lFpiwVUE5un1QXJpfm0WPc3_bYQCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/REG%2BBANNER%2Bok.png"));
    listContent.add(new Content("Paris", "Paris is the capital city of France", "https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-GsQJ555D954/XY6evcg32PI/AAAAAAAAOlg/RwJ6XUmnVP8bdIG8uXMyZd5eE6OfRsf1gCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/TURKI%2BBANNER%2B%2Bok.png"));
    listContent.add(new Content("Rio de Janeiro", "Rio has been one of Brazil's most popular destinations.", "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-gwSceqp5aUc/XY6ex9k86mI/AAAAAAAAOlk/NDk2TJqPX3cGhbmqDFRZx5nX7Fqsqui-wCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/BANNER%2BDUBAI%2Bok.png"));
    listContent.add(new Content("Sydney", "Sydney is the state capital of New South Wales.", "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-lYvUYANw3HQ/XY6etG5U8ZI/AAAAAAAAOlc/7uOsI_lFpiwVUE5un1QXJpfm0WPc3_bYQCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/REG%2BBANNER%2Bok.png"));

    return listContent;
}

public ArrayList<Slider> initSliders() {

    return slideModels();
}

//my retrofit method
    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.create();
    final Call<SliderResponse> sliderCall;
    sliderCall = apiInterface.getSlider("Bearer " + token);
    sliderCall.enqueue(new Callback<SliderResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SliderResponse> call, Response<SliderResponse> response) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.body().getData().get(0).getImage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (response.body() != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Getting slider data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (response.body().getData() != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.body().getData().get(0).getImage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    slideModels = response.body().getData();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fail getting data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fail slider data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SliderResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

ItemGroupAdapter

```
// trying with public arraylist
private void sliderView(SliderViewHolder holder) {
    SliderAdapter sliderAdapter = new SliderAdapter(context, homeFragment.initSliders());
    holder.svImage.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimationType.WORM); //set indicator animation by using SliderLayout.IndicatorAnimations. :WORM or THIN_WORM or COLOR or DROP or FILL or NONE or SCALE or SCALE_DOWN or SLIDE and SWAP!!
    holder.svImage.setSliderTransformAnimation(SliderAnimations.SIMPLETRANSFORMATION);
    holder.svImage.setAutoCycleDirection(SliderView.AUTO_CYCLE_DIRECTION_BACK_AND_FORTH);
    holder.svImage.setIndicatorSelectedColor(Color.WHITE);
    holder.svImage.setIndicatorUnselectedColor(Color.GRAY);
    holder.svImage.setScrollTimeInSec(3);
    holder.svImage.setAutoCycle(true);
    holder.svImage.startAutoCycle();
    holder.svImage.setSliderAdapter(sliderAdapter);
}

//ex
private void menuView(MenuViewHolder holder){
    MenuAdapter menuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(context, initMenus());
    holder.rvList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    holder.rvList.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a class e.g. **City.java** :

```
public class City {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String imageUrl;

    public City(String name, String description, String imageUrl) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public City() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
   }
```

Declare your `ArrayList` as follows :

```
private ArrayList<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();
```

And fill the `ArrayList` with cities in your response :

```
 public void onResponse(Call<SliderResponse> call, Response<SliderResponse> response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++){
                    City city = new City();
                    city.setName(response.body().getData().get(i).getName());
                    city.setDescription(response.body().getData().get(i).getDescription());
                    city.setImageUrl(response.body().getData().get(i).getImage());
                    cities.add(city);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, but i've been done doing that. Please check my homeFragment, there's public ArrayList include models, i need to put it there then call in my itemgroupAdapter with homeFragment.initSliders();